# Distance of a GPS coordinate from a polyline

Tags: python, gps, maps, shapely, polyline

I've created this code to measure the distance between a given GPS point and a polyline, using the Python package Shapely.

```
def is_coordinate_near_polyline(polyline_coords, target_coord, threshold_distance):

    # Convert the polyline coordinates to a LineString object
    polyline = LineString(polyline_coords)
    
    # Convert the target coordinate to a Point object
    target_point = Point(target_coord)
    
    # Iterate through each line segment of the polyline
    min_distance = float('inf')  # Initialize with a large value
    for i in range(len(polyline_coords) - 1):
        segment_start = Point(polyline_coords[i][0], polyline_coords[i][1])
        segment_end = Point(polyline_coords[i+1][0], polyline_coords[i+1][1])
        segment = LineString([segment_start, segment_end])
        
        # Calculate the distance from the target coordinate to the line segment
        distance = target_point.distance(segment)
        
        # Update the minimum distance if a smaller distance is found
        min_distance = min(min_distance, distance)
    
    # Compare the minimum distance to the threshold distance
    return min_distance <= threshold_distance
```

I think it works properly, but I do not really understand what is the measurement unit used. Is it degrees?

My objective is to understand if a user is following correctly the path provided by the polyline.

What can be a proper value for the threshold?
All the points are formatted as [lat,lon]

Comment: sounds like it's not going to work as you're using spherical coordinates in Cartesian calculations.  specifically, distances more than a few megameters and near the poles are where things will catastrophically fail.  https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html has some relevant calculations and should be easy to translate into Python